# pandas dataframe returning max value for a date when index isn't unique

Tags: python, pandas

I've got a pretty simple dataframe and I want the max row for every date.

```
all_data = pd.DataFrame([{'Date': pd.to_datetime('1/1/2022'), 'Name': 'John', 'Score': 92},
                         {'Date': pd.to_datetime('1/1/2022'), 'Name': 'Mike', 'Score': 87},
                         {'Date': pd.to_datetime('1/1/2022'), 'Name': 'Sally', 'Score': 79},
                         {'Date': pd.to_datetime('1/2/2022'), 'Name': 'John', 'Score': 85},
                         {'Date': pd.to_datetime('1/2/2022'), 'Name': 'Mike', 'Score': 91},
                         {'Date': pd.to_datetime('1/2/2022'), 'Name': 'Sally', 'Score': 88},
                         {'Date': pd.to_datetime('1/3/2022'), 'Name': 'John', 'Score': 88},
                         {'Date': pd.to_datetime('1/3/2022'), 'Name': 'Mike', 'Score': 85},
                         {'Date': pd.to_datetime('1/3/2022'), 'Name': 'Sally', 'Score': 96}])
```

This works great:

```
idx = all_data.groupby('Date')['Score'].idxmax()
print(all_data.loc[idx])

        Date   Name  Score
0 2022-01-01   John     92
4 2022-01-02   Mike     91
8 2022-01-03  Sally     96
```

But when I set the index on the date column it doesn't work anymore since the index matches all the rows

```
all_data = all_data.set_index('Date')
idx = all_data.groupby('Date')['Score'].idxmax()
print(all_data.loc[idx])

             Name  Score
Date                    
2022-01-01   John     92
2022-01-01   Mike     87
2022-01-01  Sally     79
2022-01-02   John     85
2022-01-02   Mike     91
2022-01-02  Sally     88
2022-01-03   John     88
2022-01-03   Mike     85
2022-01-03  Sally     96
```

Comment: Why it is important to perform this action while Date is defined as index?

Comment: This is a simple representation of a much larger existing data set.  If the correct solution is to remove the Date index, it's something I could probably do but I'd prefer something cleaner and more efficient than removing and readding the index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If duplicated `DatetimeIndex` is possible use [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) with remove duplicated `DatetimeIndex` by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`Index.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.duplicated.html):

```
all_data = all_data.set_index('Date')

df = all_data.sort_values('Score')
out = df[~df.index.duplicated(keep='last')]
print(out)
             Name  Score
Date                    
2022-01-02   Mike     91
2022-01-01   John     92
2022-01-03  Sally     96
```

Alternative is get all maximal `Scores` if unique:

```
all_data = all_data.set_index('Date')

out = all_data[all_data['Score'].eq(all_data.groupby('Date')['Score'].transform('max'))]
print(out)
             Name  Score
Date                    
2022-01-01   John     92
2022-01-02   Mike     91
2022-01-03  Sally     96
```

... else get again duplicated `DatetimeIndex`:

```
#changed data - double Score = 96
all_data = pd.DataFrame([{'Date': pd.to_datetime('1/1/2022'), 'Name': 'John', 'Score': 92},
                         {'Date': pd.to_datetime('1/1/2022'), 'Name': 'Mike', 'Score': 87},
                         {'Date': pd.to_datetime('1/1/2022'), 'Name': 'Sally', 'Score': 79},
                         {'Date': pd.to_datetime('1/2/2022'), 'Name': 'John', 'Score': 85},
                         {'Date': pd.to_datetime('1/2/2022'), 'Name': 'Mike', 'Score': 91},
                         {'Date': pd.to_datetime('1/2/2022'), 'Name': 'Sally', 'Score': 88},
                         {'Date': pd.to_datetime('1/3/2022'), 'Name': 'John', 'Score': 88},
                         {'Date': pd.to_datetime('1/3/2022'), 'Name': 'Mike', 'Score': 96},
                         {'Date': pd.to_datetime('1/3/2022'), 'Name': 'Sally', 'Score': 96}])
```

---

```
all_data = all_data.set_index('Date')

out = all_data[all_data['Score'].eq(all_data.groupby('Date')['Score'].transform('max'))]
print(out)
             Name  Score
Date                    
2022-01-01   John     92
2022-01-02   Mike     91
2022-01-03   Mike     96
2022-01-03  Sally     96
```

First solution in another data:

```
all_data = all_data.set_index('Date')

df = all_data.sort_values('Score')
out = df[~df.index.duplicated(keep='last')]
print(out)
             Name  Score
Date                    
2022-01-02   Mike     91
2022-01-01   John     92
2022-01-03  Sally     96
```

Comment: Those worked.  Took me a while to wrap my head around the keep="last" concept.   Until I realized that's the item you want to be "False" i.e. not a duplicate.  So I guess the expected pattern of the duplicated function is to return a mask (duplicates = True) and apply it with the "not" operator to get original item and not the duplicates.   Thanks.